# In C# how to inject all instances of generic interface into a single constructor using the generic's base class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dependency-injection, interface

I have defined the following interface:

```
public interface ICustomService<T> where T : CustomObject
{
   IEnumerable<T> GetById(int Id);
   ...
}
```

And 2 implementations of it where `MyObject1` & `MyObject2` both inherit from `CustomObject`

```
public class CustomService1 : ICustomService<MyObject1>
{
    public IEnumerable<MyObject1> GetById(int Id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
public class CustomService2 : ICustomService<MyObject2>
{
    public IEnumerable<MyObject2> GetById(int Id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I try registering both of these as `ICustomService<CustomObject>` but get the error:

> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'CustomerService1' to 'ICustomService<CustomObject>'

Instead registering like this:

```
services.AddTransient<ICustomService<MyObject1>, CustomService1>();
services.AddTransient<ICustomService<MyObject2>, CustomService2>();
```

When registering like above, my IEnumerable `services` is empty:

```
public ThirdService(IEnumerable<ICustomService<CustomObject>> services)
{
    
}
```

How can I inject all implementation of `ICustomService` into `ThirdService`?

I'm trying to do this so that `ThirdService` can be given an ID and then fetch all `CustomObject` with that Id using `GetById` on all the services.

Comment: Seems like they are repositories, not services.

Comment: generally only because `MyObject` inherits `CustomObject` does not mean that `ICustomService<MyObject>` also inherits `ICustomService<CustomObject>`. This only works if your interface is co-variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there are no additional interface methods that have parameters of type `T`, mutable properties of type `T`, or methods that return a generic type that uses `T` in a non-covariant way, you can make that `T` covariant using `out`:

```
public interface ICustomService<out T> where T : CustomObject
```

This would make your registration attempt valid:

```
services.AddTransient<ICustomService<CustomObject>, CustomService1>();
services.AddTransient<ICustomService<CustomObject>, CustomService2>();
```

[Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) ensures that `CustomService1` and `CustomService2` can safely be used in place of a `ICustomService<CustomObject>`, despite them both declaring a subclass of `MyObject` as the generic argument.

Comment: Did you make a mistake in your example by Adding ICustomService<MyObject, CustomService2>() ?  maybe you meant ICustomService<CustomObject> otherwise I dont see this solving the OP's problem of allowing them all to be injected as IEnumerable

Comment: @drowhunter Yes, it was a mistake. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a marker interface `ICustomService`

**Interfaces:**

```
// New marker interface
public interface ICustomService {}

// Derive marker interface
public interface ICustomService<T> : ICustomService where T : CustomObject
{
   IEnumerable<T> GetById(int Id);
   ...
}
```

**Registrations:**

```
services.AddTransient<ICustomService, CustomService1>();
services.AddTransient<ICustomService, CustomService2>();
```

**Resolve dependency injected Services:**

```
public ThirdService(IEnumerable<ICustomService> services)
{
    
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the services you inject wont be abke to have GetById() called on them.  unless you cast to ICustomService<T> first