# In C#, for a list of derived classes, how to use the appropriate generic interface implementation?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface, architecture

This question follows on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71470836/9100849) however is different as the interface is now using T for parameters as well as for outputs. Hence the `out` or `in` solution doesn't work.

I have defined the following interface:

```
public interface IDrawService<T> where T : Shape
{
   T DrawShape(T shape);
   ...
}
```

and two implementations of it where `Triangle` and `Square` both inherit from `Shape`:

```
public class TriangleDrawService: IDrawService<Triangle>
{
    public Triangle Draw(Triangle shape)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
public class SquareDrawService : IDrawService<Square>
{
    public Square Draw(Square shape)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have an `IEnumerable<Shape>` and need to draw each shape using the appropriate `IDrawService`:

```
IEnumerable<Shape> myShapes = new List<Shape>(){ new Triangle(), new Square()}

foreach (Shape s in myShapes){
    //TODO: Service.Draw(Shape) ???
}
```

How can I inject all services into this class and then use the appropriate service for each shape in the list?

I have tried this implementation:

```
internal static IDrawService<T> GetServiceForShape<T>(this IEnumerable<IShapeServiceMarker> services, T shape) where T : Shape
{
    var shapeServices = services.Where(service => service.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(i =>
                                i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDrawService<>) &&
                                    i.GetGenericArguments().First() == shape.GetType()));

    return (IDrawService<T>)shapeServices.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This works on individual shapes, however when running with IEnumerable I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
> 'TriangleDrawService' to type 'IDrawService'1[Shape]

as `T` then becomes `Shape` instead of the correct specific shape.

Example classes:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Triangle : Shape
{
    public int TriangleSpecificProps { get; set; }
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    public int SquareSpecificProps { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

TL:DR: If I have a list of objects of different types. And I have a list of services; 1 service for each object type. How can I get & use the correct service for each object in the list of objects?

Comment: Sometime covariance and contravariance can save you but since your `Draw` method both accepts a `T` and returns a `T`, the interface must be invariant. Which basically means casting isn't going to help - a `IDrawService<Triangle>` is *not* related to an `IDrawService<Shape>`.

Comment: Seems like an odd way to design this. You have to find the right object type, and then pass it the right shape type. Is there no way to make shapes responsible for drawing themselves? Or have a common draw object that correctly draws whichever shape is given?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is what I am finding. Covariance saved me last time (see linked question) however I need a different solution now

Comment: @JonathanWood the actual use case is not drawing of shapes but I've used this to simplify the question. In the actual solution the draw services each reach out to different external systems and hence it makes sense to keep them separated. 

I don't think I can put the methods themselves on the shapes themselves as these are in the domain layer while the logic is all in the application & infrastructure layer (Clean Architecture)

Answer (score 0):

You could derive your services from `IDrawService<Shape>`, for instance:

```
public class TriangleDrawService: IDrawService<Shape>
{

    public Shape DrawShape(Shape shape)
    {
          return Draw((Triangle) shape);
    }
    private Triangle Draw(Triangle shape)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course, this leaves you in the situation to find a different mechanics for identifying the correct service for a certain shape.

The "classic" OO mechanic would be to inject the corresponding service through the constructor of each shape into the shape itself at construction time. Then the shape could provide a method `GetDrawService` or simply `Draw`, delegating the drawing of itself to the stored service.

If you do not want this for a certain reason (maybe `IDrawService` is defined in a layer not available at the place where the shapes are implemented), add a method `GetShapeType` to the service which returns the type of shape supported:

```
public interface IDrawService<T> where T : Shape
{
   T DrawShape(T shape);

   System.Type GetShapeType();
}

public class TriangleDrawService: IDrawService<Shape>
{
    System.Type GetShapeType()
    {
        return typeof(Triangle);
    }
}
```

This gives you the type you can compare with when searching through the list of services:

```
IDrawService<Shape> GetServiceForShape<Shape>(this IEnumerable<IDrawService<Shape>> services, Shape shape) 
{
    return services.Where(
       service => service.GetShapeType() == shape.GetType()).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. One question: with this example how would I solve the issue of having an array of Shapes and needing to get the correct service for each of them?

Comment: @RyanGaudion: see my complete answer.

Comment: @RyanGaudion usually you would give the parent class an abstract method like `InitStuff( IConfigurationObject )` which every child is forced then to override. The parameter for this method is an interface that each configuration object has to agree to. This way you can simply call the initialization method and the child implementation will take care of that

Comment: @Doc Brown - Thanks for the updated answer. I'm using "Clean Architecture" for this application with shapes in the domain layer and draw services in the application layer. How would I be able to add "Draw" to the domain objects to call upwards to the application layer?

Comment: @MongZhu thank you for your reply. I'm not sure I understand your explanation. Would you be able to provide a code example for me to take a look at?

Comment: @RyanGaudion: isn't my second approach clear? It should allow exactly this.

Comment: @DocBrown I think this is the bit I don't get: "inject the corresponding service through the constructor of each shape into the shape itself at construction time". These shapes are in the domain layer which has no reference to the application layer (where the services are).

Comment: @RyanGaudion: yes, that's why I scetched a second approach which works for that case-

Comment: The domain layer only needs to see the `IDrawService<T>` interface for dependency injection. Not the concrete implementations.

Comment: @DocBrown the new solution looks like it'll work. Syntactically though `TriangleDrawService` implements `IDrawService<Shape>` which is saying via syntax that TriangleDrawService can draw any shape? I know we can put protections around this. Just wanted to ask if there is a cleaner solution that syntactically makes sense? Are there known design patterns for solving a situation like this that I can look into?

Comment: *"which is saying via syntax that TriangleDrawService can draw any shape"* - no. It says that TriangleDrawService implements the methods of the interface `IDrawService<Shape>`, no less, no more.